# Can I reference a repository of a different entity within a specific entity service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

In DDD (Domain-Driven Design): Can I reference a repository of a different entity within a specific entity service?

For example (I'm sorry if the example is a bit out of context):

Knowing that there is the **Student** and **StudentAddress** entities

```
public class StudentService : ServiceBase<Student>, IStudentService {

    private readonly IStudentAddressRepository _studentAddressRepository; // Is this reference valid?
    private readonly IStudentRepository _studentRepository;

    public StudentService(IStudentRepository repository, IStudentAddressRepository studentAddressRepository) : base(repository)
    {
        //... IoC
    }    
}
```

Is this reference for StudentAddressRepository or even for the entity StudentAddress valid ?

Comment: What is the service doing?

Comment: It looks weird that `StudentService` "is a" student repository *and* "has a" student repository. I don't think it should be a repository. But this question is rather opinion-based.

Comment: I'm sorry. I made a mistake. It's really ServiceBase

Comment: What's ServiceBase for?

Comment: This is a Base Class with similar services between entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in DDD terms conceptually it is ok, but sometimes might point to a possible modelling problem. A little more detail regarding why the service exists would be helpful.

In the blue book, Eric Evans has an example of a Funds Transfer service that interacts with two objects - Account and Ledger. I'd implement this by having a domain service that accepts the two objects, rather than having their respective repositories in the domain service constructor - keep the responsibility of loading them in the application layer.

For example, something like:

```
public static class StudentService {

    public static void WhateverItIsYouAreDoing(Student student, StudentAddress studentAddress) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Another thing to think of when adding a domain service, is does it add to the ubiquitous language? Can you discuss the service with a domain expert? I.e. "Funds Transfer service" is something you can imagine talking about to the domain expert.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Answering the above question: At first I would like to recover student addresses without using lazy loading, so I came to the question of whether it would be correct to call this repository (IStudentAddressRepository) and use it within the Student service for this purpose, because it would already bring the student with their address.

Comment: I wouldn't use a service for this, that's not really what they are for. If you want to return addresses along with the student I'd just have a method on the StudentRepository - GetWithAddresses or something like this. However, it depends what you're trying to do and why you need the addresses :)

Comment: I need the addresses to display on UI (MVC). Do you advise me that data recovery is between Application <---> Repository? (I'm initializing DDD).

Comment: Just keep it simple and load them from the repository, there's no domain logic associated here so no need for any added complexity such as a domain service

Comment: Thanks, Tom. Just to be sure, is there any problem initializing the IStudentAdressRepository interface in the StudentRepository class constructor for IoC ?

Comment: I'd probably just have a single repository, IStudentRepository that internally loads the addresses for the student.

Comment: If it just for a web view I actually wouldn't even have a repository, just some data access that brought back what I need for the view. If you read about CQRS this would be the read side.